# Random points uniformly distributed on the surface of a sphere

Tags: random, spherical-coordinates

Assume I need to generate (pseudo)random points uniformly distributed on the surface of a sphere with radius $1$ and center at coordinate's origin.

The obvious, but incorrect, approach would be to use spherical coordinate system: pick up values of $\phi\in]0, 2\pi]$ and $\theta\in]0,\pi]$ from uniform distribution, this would give us a random point $(\phi, \theta)$ on a sphere.

The not-so-obvious, but correct way of doing this (thanks to comments) as explained here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html :

choose $u$ and $v$ from uniform distribution $(0, 1)$. Then

$$
\phi=2\pi u 
$$
$$
\theta=cos^{-1}(2v - 1)
$$

gives me a correct distribution.

Now, what if instead I take points $\boldsymbol{p}$ with coordinates $x$,$y$ and $z$ from uniform distribution on $[-1, 1]$ interval (call it $U(-1, -1)$) and then normalize the results (neglect the case when all three coordinates are zero)?

That is:

$$
\boldsymbol{p}_s=\frac{\boldsymbol p}{\parallel \boldsymbol p \parallel}
$$

Will it still give uniform distribution on the sphere?

What if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are taken from the Normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$ : $N(0, 1)$ ?

Is there any way to check the 'quality' of the distribution?

Comment: The "obvious" approach does not produce points uniformly distributed on the sphere. Don't forget that the sphere is curved, so there is more area near the equator ($\theta \approx \pi / 2$) than near the poles ($\theta \approx 0$, $\theta \approx \pi$).

Comment: This is a well studied problem. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html which describes why the `obvious approach' would not work.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the question. Still, the link does not explain how to verify the quality of the distribution (apart from visual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a$ is a random point from the distribution with probability density function $p : S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, and $X$ is any measurable subset of the sphere $S^2$. Then we have

$$\int_{b \in S^2} p(b)\, d\sigma = 1$$

$$ P(a \in X) = \int_{b \in X} p(b)\, d\sigma $$

"Uniform distribution" means that the probability the point is a member of any measurable subset of the domain is proportional to the measure of that set. For the sphere $S^2$, the standard measure is the area (the surface integral of the constant function $1$). So if $p$ has this property, then for every measurable $X \subseteq S^2$,

$$ \frac{P(a \in X)}{P(a \in S^2)} = \frac{\int_X d\sigma}{\int_{S^2} d\sigma} $$

$P(a \in S^2)=1$, and $\int_{S^2} d\sigma$ is the surface area of the whole sphere, which is $4 \pi$. With the formula for $P(a \in X)$ above, this gives

$$ P(a \in X) = \int_{b \in X} p(b)\, d\sigma = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_X d\sigma $$

The only way this can be true for a continuous $p$ and for all subsets $X \subseteq S^2$ is if $p(b) = \frac{1}{4 \pi}$ everywhere.

In spherical coordinates with $0 \leq \phi < 2\pi$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, and $\rho=1$, we have

$$ P(\phi < \phi_0 \land \theta < \theta_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^{\phi_0} \int_0^{\theta_0} \sin \theta\, d\theta\, d\phi = \frac{1}{4\pi} (1-\cos \theta) \phi $$

We can satisfy this by

$$ \begin{align*} P(\theta < \theta_0) &= \frac{1-\cos \theta_0}{2} \\
P(\phi < \phi_0) &= \frac{\phi_0}{2\pi} \end{align*} $$

If we have independent uniformly random variables $u$ and $v$, we can transform them to these distributions by inverting those equations:
$$ \begin{align*}
u = \frac{\phi}{2\pi} &\implies \phi = 2\pi u \\
v = \frac{1-\cos \theta}{2} &\implies \theta = \cos^{-1}(1-2v)
\end{align*} $$

The given correct transformation in the question is also fine, since it differs just by $\phi \mapsto 2\pi - \phi$.

The proposed distribution with spherical coordinates $\phi$ and $\theta$ independent and uniformly random gives

$$ P(\phi < \phi_0 \land \theta < \theta_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \phi_0 \theta_0 $$

This does not match the $P(\phi < \phi_0 \land \theta < \theta_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi} (1-\cos \theta) \phi$ for the distribution uniform on the sphere.

Another proposed distribution takes $x,y,z$ from independent and uniformly random distributions, then takes the unit vector in the direction of $(x,y,z)$. If $\theta_0 < \frac{\pi}{4}$, then the probability $P(\theta < \theta_0)$ is the volume of the cone whose apex is the origin and whose base is the disk $x^2+y^2 \leq \sin^2 \theta, z=1$, divided by the total volume $8$ of the distribution's cube $(-1,1) \times (-1,1) \times (-1,1)$. This volume is $\frac{\pi}{3} \sin^2 \theta$. This does not match the $P(\theta < \theta_0) = (1-\cos \theta_0)/2$ for the distribution uniform on the sphere.

Finally, a proposed distribution takes $x,y,z$ from independent Gaussian distributions. So the probability density function for the original $(x,y,z)$ is

$$ p_G(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^3 e^{-x^2/\sigma^2} e^{-y^2/\sigma^2} e^{-z^2/\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{\sigma^3 \pi^{3/2}} e^{-\rho^2/\sigma^2} $$

Then given a measurable set $X \subseteq S^2$,

$$ \begin{align*}
P(a \in X) &= \int_{\{(x,y,z) \mid (x/\rho, y/\rho, z/\rho) \in X\}} p_G(x,y,z)\, dx\, dy\, dz \\
P(a \in X) &= \int_{\{(\phi,\theta,\rho) \mid (\cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos \theta) \in X\}} p_G(x,y,z)\, \rho^2 \sin \theta\, d\rho\, d\theta\, d\phi \\
P(a \in X) &= \frac{1}{\sigma^3 \pi^{3/2}} \int_{X} d\sigma \int_0^\infty e^{-\rho^2/\sigma^2} \rho^2 d\rho \\
P(a \in X) &= \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{X} d\sigma
\end{align*} $$

This method does give the correct distribution. (It might take a little more CPU time than the other correct methods if they're all converted to computer algorithms.)

A note: You used the $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinate variables in the swapped meaning from the way I usually see and use them. I've followed your usage in this answer, but make sure you're using $x = \sin \theta \cos \phi, y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = \cos \theta$.

Comment: Thank you for the full answer. From wikipedia : "Several different conventions exist for representing the three coordinates, and for the order in which they should be written. The use of $(r, \theta\, \phi) $ to denote radial distance, inclination (or elevation), and azimuth, respectively, is common practice in physics, and is specified by ISO standard...". However, according to the same article in Wikipedia using $\phi$ for inclination (or elevation) and $\theta$ for azimuth is common in mathematics.